# How can we solve conversion problem that loses precision ? (Xcode 11.2)

Tags: warnings, precision, implicit-conversion, xcode11, swift5

Since Xcode 11.2, I have this warning: `Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'const GULLoggerLevel' (aka 'const enum GULLoggerLevel') to 'int'`.

This warning refers me to this line:

```
dispatch_async(sGULClientQueue, ^{
    asl_log(sGULLoggerClient, NULL, level, "%s", logMsg.UTF8String);
  })
```

This line is part of this block:

```
     NSString *logMsg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:message arguments:args_ptr];
  logMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s - %@[%@] %@", sVersion, service, messageCode, logMsg];
  dispatch_async(sGULClientQueue, ^{
    asl_log(sGULLoggerClient, NULL, level, "%s", logMsg.UTF8String);
  });
```

Can anybody help me with this warning ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you just have to replace"level" by "(int)level"